# What's the equivalent to +[NSObject load] for category on instance

Tags: objective-c, categories

As you on categories can override the static method

```
+ (void)load
{
    // do any setup for the class
}
```

I'm wondering how I can do the same pr instance. Is it really necessary to swizzle the init-method?

Comment: So the main purpose is to have some code that will be called each time when ANY object is being initialized? am I right?

Comment: I wasn't able to find any possible solution but to swizzle `init` method of `NSObject class`, but when you do so, you need to be Really careful and disable ARC for code that is used in swizzled init. It's because there's alot objects in iOS those are subclasses of [NSObject class] but will crash immidiately on any -retain or -release those ARC is putting in. Take a look here https://github.com/DyCI/dyci-main/blob/master/Dynamic%20Code%20Injection/dyci/Classes/Injections/NSObject%2BDyCInjection.m

Comment: This has all the hallmarks of 'why would you want do even do this'. What kind of code would you want to run each time you initialise an instance? I'm sure you can have a base class that implements some kind of functionality in the init method that does what you'd like without screwing with the standard alloc/init lifecycle.

Comment: @Jessedc well, most category methods are simple and don't need any prior initialization. Some more sophisticated do. I'm not saying that's the way to go, but knowledge is king no matter what you say.

Answer (score 0):

No, AFAIK there is no method for this. Instead do something like this

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface NSObject (XXXCategory)
@end

@implementation NSObject (XXXCategory)

- (void)xxx_setup
{
    static void * XXXDidSetupPropertKey;
    NSNumber *didSetupValue = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, XXXDidSetupPropertKey);    BOOL didSetup = [didSetupValue boolValue];
    if(!didSetup)
    {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, XXXDidSetupPropertKey, @YES, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
        NSLog(@"Setting up category");
    }
}

- (void)xxx_doSomething
{
    [self xxx_setup];
    NSLog(@"do something");
}

- (void)xxx_doSomethingElse
{
    [self xxx_setup];
    NSLog(@"do something else");
}

@end
```

When tested like this

```
NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
[obj xxx_doSomething];
[obj xxx_doSomethingElse];
```

The result is

```
2014-02-28 10:21:04.024 Untitled 2[27026:507] Setting up category
2014-02-28 10:21:04.025 Untitled 2[27026:507] do something
2014-02-28 10:21:04.026 Untitled 2[27026:507] do something else
```